# trying to parse csv file in python 3.4

Tags: python, parsing, csv

So I'm new in parsing csv files and I'm using the pycharm 4.5 IDE. I'm having a problem parsing a csv file from crunchbase (the file I am dealing with is pretty huge) and i get this UnicodeEndcodeError, I want to know why this is happening.

(it's below to see the full error )

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table[0])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 273-291:
character maps to <undefined>
```

My code for parsing the csv file is below this line:

```
import csv

def parseCsvFile():
#The code below reads csv file and puts each category in a list
 filename = input("Type file name: ")
 input_csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(filename, encoding="utf8"))
 for row in input_csv_file:
     print (row)

csvfilename.close()
```

I didn't want to fully show my code on here because its a private project. I'm not so desperate but lost why my output code appearing as it is. If anybody has a better way to code, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you atleast show the complete traceback?

Comment: Typically cp1252.py errors have to do with displaying Unicode on the command/terminal prompt, not in the csv itself. Try not printing Unicode to the console, i.e. don't print row to console - write it to a file as a test and see if you get that error still

Comment: Thanks Dan :D appreciate the helps

Comment: @pantaleon5193 It could also be that this file is not encoded UTF8.

Comment: do you know how i can check if it is not encoded?

Comment: yeah Dan I did what you said and i'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

can you please let us know why you are using the utf8 encoding ??? 
do your project specified that as one of the requirements ???
if it's not then you can skip that option and it would solve your problem

Comment: my project doesn't specify, i just looked up utf8, I realize i didn't need it. Thanks Tarun

Comment: any good sources to learn how to skip the UnicodeDecodeError?